# Is it possible to put a PHP script inside an actionscript text area

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

Let us say that you have an ActionScript.swf application with a text area written in MXML, and a PHP file (which is querying a remote MySQL database) in the same directory as the .swf file. Is it possible to place the PHP script inside the text area so that it imports the values from the MySQL database into the text area? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. But there are work arounds, like writing a PHP class which will parse your text into real PHP code on serverside when you send the request for the datas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the alternative, can I import an XML menu into a ActionScript object? For example, could I import the following set of XML commands so that when a particular menu item is selected, a particular event is fired?                        `<menu>
<item name="Action To Take" action="No action">
  <sub name="Dalek" action="exterminate" />
 <sub name="Cyberman" action="delete" />
 <sub name="Human" action="run" />  
 </item>
</menu>`

Comment: You can fill up a flash component, combobox with XML data, then add some listeners to it. Yes it is possible.